What type of Schengen visa does a sailor's family need to onboard from the Suez?
I am a sailor planning to call my family onboard with me on the ship from the Suez or Antifer. What type of schengen visa should my family apply to sign on from here?

You don't mean "call", you mean "invite"

By ‘sign on’, do you mean ‘join the ship (as passengers’? Or will your family be travelling as sailors too?

There aren't really different types of Schengen visas. There are a lot of special rules for seafarers but I don't see how they would apply here.
Instead, your family would simply be treated like passengers, which also means they will need to fulfill all the regular rules apply (having a credible plan, sufficient financial means, etc.)

Just that there may be special rules on port of entry: where and when (the first port): do not expect all ports have immigration stuff.

@GiacomoCatenazzi We are not talking about some random marina though, Le Havre is one of the largest French ports.

I don't see Le Havre mentioned anywhere in the question, @Relaxed...?

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The OP could have been a little clearer on the route but Antifer is the oil terminal of HAROPA (the new name for Le Havre port).

Generally speaking, there are few ships that would go all the way from Suez to Le Havre and call in small harbors. Usually, that's left to feeder ships that don't go as far.
